# Bootstrap navbar dropdown not working on Catalina?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, safari, macos-catalina

We are using bootstrap for a navbar with dropdown and it works fine in other browsers but not in Safari 13 on Catalina (but it works in Safari 13 with earlier OS!).

The cursor sees a link but nothing happens when clicked, the menu does not open.

FYI this is not an online site, html files are locally stored (I know macOS/Safari are restrictive with that but I cannot find if it plays a role here).

Code goes like this:

```
<header role="banner">
         <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-mycompany bg-primary mb-4 ">           
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
               <div class="navbar-nav flex-row">                 
                  <div class="nav-item dropdown mx-3">
                     <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span>Item1</span></a>
                     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item   " href="my/link1.html">
                           <span>Item1b</span></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item   " href="my/link2.html">
                           <span>Item1c</span></a>                        
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </nav>
      </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any reason your code wouldn't work in macOS Catalina / Safari 13 (which is the environment in which I am testing) but I do see why your navigational menu might not display.

`navbar-expand-lg` means that the navigational menu will be collapsed unless the browser viewport meets the `lg` breakpoint or greater.  But since you do not have the toggle component in place the collapsed menu can never be toggled active.

Unless `.navbar-mycompany` applies style changes to the hyperlink color of your navigational menu, the absence of either `.navbar-light` or `.navbar-dark` will also result in those hyperlinks using the default color scheme... which happens to match the color of `.bg-primary`.  So even in large environments the hyperlinks will blend in with the background.

So simply by altering `.navbar-expand-lg` to a smaller breakpoint, applying one of Bootstraps predefined Navbar link schemes, and adding in the necessary toggle we get a fully functional navigational menu

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header role="banner">
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary mb-4">           
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <div class="navbar-nav flex-row">                 
        <div class="nav-item dropdown mx-3">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span>Item1</span></a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="my/link1.html"><span>Item1b</span></a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="my/link2.html"><span>Item1c</span></a>                        
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. We do have a button with toggler, I just omitted from the snippet when I anonymized the code. Again this code works fine in other browser/OS and earlier Safari/macOS. Our files are in the Applications folder so I think safety is blocking the bootstrap javascripts.

Comment: I would recommend updating your question with more of your code then. Also, have you opened up the inspector in Safari to ensure that there aren't any JS errors?